# Trying to add a discount code to the "add to cart" button on landing page in [Shopify]

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am doing some edits to a section on a template in shopify. The request was to show a reduced price on the product and when the user clicks "add to cart" it will apply the discount code to their cart along with adding the product to cart.

This is to make it look more seamless to the user.

They are also using a 3rd party app called rebuy which acts as their drawer cart.

The code I have is:

```
    <p class="price_"> Save 30% Now <br> <del>{{ product_.price | money }}</del><br> $27.00</p>  
    <div style="padding-top:20px !important;" class="description_product title-description font-size-sixteen">{{ section.settings.product_description }}</div>    
       <div class="button-featured-product">
      <form method="post" action="/cart/add">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product_.variants.first.id }}" />
        <input style="" type="submit" value="{{ section.settings.buy_now_button_text }}" class="custom-featured-button btn_custom mobile-button"/>
       </form>
       </div>
```

I tried adding this to it but nothing:

```
<input type="hidden" name="discount" value="FREE30" />
```

I also tried to use the id's from inspecting the rebuy app apply discount section.

```
<p class="price_"> Save 30% Now <br> <del>{{ product_.price | money }}</del><br> $27.00</p>  
<div style="padding-top:20px !important;" class="description_product title-description font-size-sixteen">{{ section.settings.product_description }}</div>    
<div class="button-featured-product">
  <form method="post" action="/cart/add" onsubmit="applyDiscountCode()">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product_.variants.first.id }}" />
    <input style="" type="submit" value="{{ section.settings.buy_now_button_text }}" class="custom-featured-button btn_custom mobile-button"/>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
function applyDiscountCode() {
  var discountCode = "FREE30"; // Change this to your discount code
  var discountInput = document.getElementById("rebuy-discount-input");
  if (discountInput) {
    discountInput.value = discountCode;
  }
}
</script>
```

Also tried to add this below the original too"

```
<script>
  $(".button").click(function(){   
    $.ajax({
      url:'https://www.unitedandfree.com/pages/soothing-oil-simple-effective-b/discount/FREE30',
      success: function(data) {
        alert("Your discount has been applied!");
      }
    });        
  });
</script>
```

I can't figure out what I might be doing wrong. Maybe you can't add a discount code along with an add to cart call?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!